# Initializing the size of std::vector

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

This may be an elementary question.. I have class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {

    private:

    vector<MyStructure> data;

    public:

    void read(const cv::FileNode& node) {
        // read data from file

        cv::FileNode n = node["MyStructure"]; 
        cv::FileNodeIterator it = n.begin(), it_end = n.end(); 
        for (int i = 0; it != it_end; ++it, ++i) {
            *it >> data[i];   // there's a problem here. 
        }
    }

}
```

Note that `it` is an iterator that points to `MyStructure` elements in container `n`.  Here's the problem I have. I don't know the size of `vector<MyStructure> data` in advance (when I construct the object). So I can't just simply assign `*it >> data[i]`. This code compiles but it will crush with a run time error. How can I fix this? The solution needs to be efficient if possible (that is, it should avoid making too many copies of `MyStructure` objects).

Comment: Um. I don't know `cv` from Adam, but if it actually holds `MyStructure` equivalencies as the dereferenced result of an FileNodeIterator dereference, then why not `std::copy(n.begin(), n.end(), std::back_inserter(data));` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried your suggestion with `std::copy(n.begin(), n.end(), std::back_inserter(data));` but it doesn't compile unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it might not by the looks of the way that iterator is used (as an extraction source, which is an interesting abstraction in itself). It would have made life much easier if it just allowed a simple eval. Ah. well./

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyStructure temp;
*it >> temp;
data.push_back(std::move(temp));
```

This avoids making too many copies of `MyStructure` objects.  It makes just enough copies.

If `n` is a container which has a `size` member function, then do this first:

```
data.reserve(n.size());
```

Comment: Good idea! I don't have C++11 compiler though.

Comment: +1 I have to plus 1 this just for the local knowledge of cv. Do dereferenced `FileNodeIterator` iterators really support a extraction operator syntax? That's interesting. I need to check out that lib kit.

Comment: @Alex: Then drop the `std::move`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have no knowledve of `cv`.  I just copied the OP's code.

Comment: Well, to me its an interesting idea, an iterator that enums an abstract container and uses extraction rather then valuation as the retrieval mechanism. Still going to check it out.

Comment: Can I use `boost::move(temp);` instead?

Comment: @Alex: I don't know much about it. But from my undersanding, you'd have to modify your class with some macros in order for it to do any good.

Comment: @WhozCraig `cv` is for OpenCV library that's used in computer vision applications. This code reads input data from an xml file.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I knew what the toolkit was, I'd just not seed something like this before. Somewhat akin to a sequence of custom input stream references. interesting idea.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, the container has a `size()` member function. This was the solution. However I think it should be `data.resize(n.size());`, if I do `data.reserve(n.size());` the program would still crush when I do `data[i]`.

Comment: @Alex: That's what the first part of my answer addresses.  If you call `push_back` `n.size()` times, you should be able to access up to `data[n.size()-1]`.  Otherwise you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley But if I know the size I can do `data.resize(n.size());` and then `*it >> data[i];` in the loop. So no need to use `std::move` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
std::deque<int> accumulate;
for(...) accumulate.push_back(...);
// Getting a continuous vector
std::vector result(accumulate.begin(), accumulate.end()):
```